# dismissModelViewControllerAnimated not working for iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

So in my iPhone 4 device after I pick a image I want the image picker popover to go away. This works in iPhone 4 but the following code doesn't work for the iPhone 5.

```
- (void) loadImage:(UIImage*) image {
float w = image.size.width;
float h = image.size.height;
float maxw = scrollView.frame.size.width;
float maxh = scrollView.frame.size.height;
float wratio = maxw / w;
float hratio = maxh / h;
float ratio = wratio < hratio ? wratio : hratio;
ratio = ratio < 1 ? ratio : 1;

int adjW = (int) (w * ratio);
int adjH = (int) (h * ratio);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(adjW, adjH));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, adjW, adjH)];

CGImageRef scaledImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[appDelegate.model setCurrentImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage: scaledImage]];
[self clear];
calcButton.enabled = YES;
trashButton.enabled = YES;
scribbleControls.enabled = YES;
[appDelegate.mergeViewCtlr setFirst];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[self loadImage:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        // called for iPad
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
else {
     // called for iPhone and tried each of the next 3 lines individually
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; <== NOT WORKING
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; <== ALSO NOT WORKING
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; <== ALSO NOT WORKING
}

[picker release];
}
```

I also noticed that it said dimissModelViewControllerAnimated has been deprecated and that instead I should use:
Use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: instead. But how would I use this? Thanks

Here is the code that presents the model view:
    - (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0: { //photo library
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
                if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
                    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
                }
                else {
                    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
                    popoverController.delegate = self;
                    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake( 250, -50, 320, 480 )
                                                       inView:[self view]
                                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                     animated:YES];
                }
            }
            else { // for iPhone
                [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE];
            }
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Photo library is empty or unavailable" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1: //camera
```

Comment: are you sure your else block is being entered? did you set a breakpoint to make sure it is? IF so, then you should try calling the dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method on picker, not self.

Comment: I am sure it is being entered because I have print statement there that I omitted above. And I have tried [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; BUT it does not work either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated::` was [deprecated in iOS6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated%3a). Use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` instead.

Comment: No problem. `presentModalViewController:animated:` was also deprecated - try using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Comment: It did not work either. What I do not understand it why is the popover only staying after I use the photolibrary. It does not stay after I use the camera.

Comment: Not sure. Someone else might have to chime in on that. Sorry bud.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

presentModalViewController, and dismissModalViewController depracated in iOS6

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[self.imagePicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

and use

```
[self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can also use `respondsToSelector` to make the cases for iOS 5 and ios6.